# loop within a loop in assembly

Tags: loops, assembly, x86

I just started programming in Assembly and I'm really confused about looping in Assembly.This is my code :

```
org 100h

Var db ?
Var2 db 65
Var3 db 0
mov ax,0
mov ah,01h
int 21h

mov Var,al

mov ah,02h
mov dl,10
int 21h

mov ah,02h
mov dl,13
int 21h

mov al,Var
sub al,64

mov cl,al

a:
    mov bl,cl
    mov ah,02h
    mov dh,Var2
    inc Var3
    mov cl,Var3
    inc Var2

b:                           
    mov ah,02h      
    mov dl,dh      
    int 21h      
    mov ah,02h      
    mov dl,0dh      
    int 21h          
    loop b     

    mov ah,02h
    mov dl,10
    int 21h

    mov ah,02h
    mov dl,13
    int 21h  

mov cl,bl
loop a

ret
```

It outputs something like this :
*(Input)*
F
*(Output)*
A
B
C
D
E
F

or 
*(Input)*
B
*(Output)*
A
B

What I want to happen is this:
*(Input)*
F
*(Output)*
A
BB
CCC
DDDD
EEEEE
FFFFFF

I really need help I spent hours racking my brain in this code. Please do so tell me what I did wrong or what I should do. Thanks

Comment: Each architecture has a different assembly/machine language, so assembly question must go with the architecture tag. An advice for you: name the label with something meaningful, don't use just one character like that. It will confuse you when writing larger programs

Comment: for a start - you should be setting cx rather than cl as your loop counter

Answer (score 1):

When using a loop variable, the `cx` register is used as the counter. So here in the inner loop

```
    loop b
```

You are using `CX` which becomes 0 in the process. Then your code continues with the outer loop

```
mov ah,02h
...
int 21h
```

And again uses `cx` which is still 0 at the point.

```
mov cl,bl
```

So this outer loop

```
loop a
```

never loops.